# Cookies in MVC4 localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have the following code:

```
public class CookieHelper
{
    public static void SetCookie(string name, string value)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(name);
        myCookie.Value = value;
        myCookie.Expires.AddMonths(1);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }

    public static HttpCookie GetCookie(string name)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name];
    }
}
```

I use this for remembering the last used option in a dropdownlist. As for now, I'm just running the app directly from VS2012 (localhost). And this works as long as I run the app. But once I stop it, and then reruns it, the cookie is not found. Is this by design, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i believe the problem lies in `myCookie.Expires.AddMonths(1)`. 
If i'm not mistaken , the default value of the `Expires` is `0001/01/01` if you add one month , the expire time is `0001/02/01/` which is less than today.

Can you try this instead? `myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);`

Comment: You were faster. That is my solution: `myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);`